# NoClassDefFoundError for Android < 5.0

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, android-multidex, jack-compiler

My app is crashing on Android < 5.0 but works for Android > 5.0. I'm using multidex and Jack compiler.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.example.lb'
    minSdkVersion 15 //versions below 14 do not support multidex
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    multiDexEnabled true
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
```

Multidex was long before added than jack compiler and it worked ok before. After adding Jack Compiler the app crashes with the following error for Android < 5.0.

```
Failed to start Crashlytics
           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit[]
                   at com.example.lb.MyApplication.attemptToStartCrashylitics(MyApplication.java:39)
                    at com.example.lb.MyApplication.startCrashlytics(MyApplication.java:91)
                    at com.example.lb.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:80)
...

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
           Process: com.geico.mobile, PID: 3460
           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.lb.MyBootstrapStarter
                  at com.example.lb.MyApplication.bootstrapApplication(MyApplication.java:49)
                   at com.example.lb.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:81)
```

Can Jack compiler cause this issue or is it something else responsible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your googl-service.json file missing api key.check your file is api_key ok?

```
   "api_key": [{
    "current_key": "hasjfhhasjhyueh78sf8fhsdhfjs8"
  }],
```

and you can use

```
    dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```